# Accessing WorldClim data?

Tags: climate

I have been trying to access WorldClim data for several days now, without success. Neither browser-based download nor `getData()` works in my case.

I have tried various end devices, on various networks, even the phone. Seems the server is not accessible. A post in their Contact form keeps unresponded since days.

Does anybody experience the same?

Specifically, to download current data you would visit http://worldclim.org/current
Trying to download the, say, 10 min resolved tmin data should result in saving http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/climate/worldclim/1_4/grid/cur/tmin_10m_bil.zip to your computer. However, each attempt with any file results in a request timeout error.

Comment: What are the precise steps that you are performing when you try to do this using your preferred method?

Comment: I can't download anything off of the WorldClim page either. Looks like something is awry with the server at UCDavis

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hm, today, downloads are working again. Unfortunately I haven"t got a clue whether my/our inquiries cured it, or if there was some other reasons. Both question through contract forum and direct email to UCDavies was not answered - kind of poor customer service for a Californian school.
I close the question, many thanks for your comments.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a comment to your question. Please place this in the comment section or edit your question to reflect updates (as your reputation is not high enough for comments).